# Ajax tabContainer Header scrollbar not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Below is the code for Ajax tabContainer Header scrollbar
 it appears that back panel of scroll bar 
is visible but the actual scrollbar  is not showing up
code for scroll bar is in script tag 
i am using overflow:scroll; overflow-y:hidden; for the scroll bar 
and  .ajax__tab_body for the tab body to move down

[image: the result of below code]

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>

          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {

                $(".ajax__tab_header").html("<div style='height:35px; overflow:scroll; overflow-y:hidden;  width:350px;         ' >" + $(".ajax__tab_header").html() + "</div>");

            })
        </script>

      <style>
            .ajax__tab_body
            {
               width:323px;
             position:absolute;
              top: 45px  ;

            } 

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
          <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
         <asp:TabContainer runat="server" 
            OnClientActiveTabChanged="ClientFunction" 
            Height="500px" ActiveTabIndex="7" Width="323px" ID="tab" BorderStyle="None"  
              ScrollBars="Auto" UseVerticalStripPlacement="false" EnableTheming="True" 
              >
        <asp:TabPanel runat="server" 
            HeaderText="Signature and Bio" ID="test" ScrollBars="Both"></asp:TabPanel>
            <ContentTemplate>
                ...
            </ContentTemplate>
        /><asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1">
             </asp:TabPanel>
             <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel2">
             </asp:TabPanel>
             <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel3" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel3">
             </asp:TabPanel>
             <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel4" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel4">
             </asp:TabPanel>
             <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel5" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel5">
             </asp:TabPanel>
             <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel6" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel6">
             </asp:TabPanel>
             <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel7" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel7">
             </asp:TabPanel>
    </asp:TabContainer><br /><br /><br /><br />






            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```